# Android firebase append existing data with new data

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase. I just want to append new data with old data without retriveing data to android eg:-

[image]

i want append data to gTopics like add music etc...

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advise you to read Firebase docs about how to read and write your data.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write